# How can I convert NSDictionary to NSData and vice versa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I am sending `NSString` and `UIImage` using bluetooth. I decided to store both in a `NSDictionary` and then convert the dictionary to `NSData`.

My question is how to convert `NSDictionary` to `NSData` and visa versa?

Answer (score 369, accepted):

**NSDictionary -> NSData:**

```
NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDictionary];
```

**NSData -> NSDictionary:**

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```

Comment: For NSData -> NSDictionary, the cast to NSDictionary seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 52):

NSDictionary -> NSData:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:yourDictionary forKey:@"Some Key Value"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[archiver release];

// Here, data holds the serialized version of your dictionary
// do what you need to do with it before you:
[data release];
```

NSData -> NSDictionary

```
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Some Key Value"] retain];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
[unarchiver release];
[data release];
```

You can do that with any class that conforms to NSCoding.

[source](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6187-nsdata-nsdictionary.html#post28415)

Comment: Not to take anything away from this answer, but just a heads that it isn't ARC compliant

Comment: Yes, my answer is from 2011 where ARC didn't exist

Answer (score 46):

Use NSJSONSerialization:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
NSData *dataFromDict = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];

NSDictionary *dictFromData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromDict
                                                             options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                               error:&error];
```

The latest returns `id`, so its a good idea to check the returned object type after you cast (here i casted to NSDictionary).

Answer (score 24):

In **Swift 2** you can do it in this way:

```
var dictionary: NSDictionary = ...

/* NSDictionary to NSData */
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionary)

/* NSData to NSDictionary */
let unarchivedDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data!) as! NSDictionary
```

In **Swift 3**:

```
/* NSDictionary to NSData */
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionary)

/* NSData to NSDictionary */
let unarchivedDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)
```

Comment: Did not work ! Swift 3 equivalent code did not work.
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dataFromNetwork)

[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. What I meant is this - Swift 3 code also did not work. My data is from 3lvis/networking HTTP library, it is of `Any?` type. But it showed error converting from `NSDictionary` to `NSData`. So I tried your code. It did not work.

Answer (score 19):

**NSDictionary from NSData**

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/09/nsdictionary-from-nsdata/

**NSDictionary to NSData**

You can use NSPropertyListSerialization class for that. Have a look at its method:

```
+ (NSData *)dataFromPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format
                              errorDescription:(NSString **)errorString
```

Returns an NSData object containing a given property list in a specified format.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution for most Mac OS developers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *responseJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData
                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                error:&error];
```

Comment: It's `response`, not `responce`.  I corrected this for you.