# How to convert JSON serialized data to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I have used this method,

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization 
       JSONObjectWithData:jsonData 
                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves 
                    error:nil];
NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@",jsonObject);
```

It's printing "jsonObject is null".
Is there any problem with "error:nil".
I am not using any url or connection methods.
I have a json file and I want to display it in a table.

Comment: Did you check that jsonData is not nil? You may want to pass an NSError object to the call if you want to get some error description.

Comment: You can find answer here [How to use NSJSONSerialization][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization

Comment: @ Ivan Dyachenko: i too did d same thing..... "NSError *myerror=nil; then "error:&myerror;"  even then i got null......

Comment: This should be called "JSON serialized data to NSDictionary", NSData to NSDictionary and vice versa conversion answer can be found here...  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5513075/4018041

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Please Try the following Code.

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];

NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"loans"];

NSLog(@"loans: %@", latestLoans);
```

Comment: then enter your url in browser and then you will get dict or array then copy all data and paste it in this link http://jsonlint.com/        if your json is valid then it will show or if there is any error then will show null.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone is here to see swift code:

> **NSData to NSDictionary**

```
let dictionary:NSDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(jsonData)! as NSDictionary
```

> **NSData to NSString**

```
let resstr = NSString(data: res, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: for swift 4:       let dictionary:NSDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)! as! NSDictionary

Answer (score 6):

Check your json input, could it be that your root element is neither a dictionary nor an array? The documentation says you have to specify NSJSONReadingAllowFragments as the option in this case.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSData *jsonData = [@"{ \"key1\": \"value1\" }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization 
           JSONObjectWithData:jsonData 
                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves 
                        error:nil];
    NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@",jsonObject);

    [p release];
}
```

Output:

```
2012-09-26 16:06:51.610 Untitled[19164:707] jsonObject is {
    key1 = value1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

This is just a more succinct version of the top post.

Answer (score -1):

> let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary