# How to Post data in iOS?

Tags: ios, post

I am doing an instagram appliaction. In that I need to post like on Images. I am not able to post . I am following instgram API. We need to use following url

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes
```

We need to set media id  like

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/649114513807113248_1032025382/likes
```

> media id = 649114513807113248_1032025382

**My code to post:**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString            stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/649114513807113248_1032025382/likes"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                             delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

But like is not posting. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Did you implement the NSURLConnection delegates? Are you getting a response? What does it say?

Comment: Ya I have implemented didReceiveData() delegate but its showing some numbers , no valid data

Comment: Can you post the output here?

Comment: Can u please convert the data into string and log it then show here       NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];                           NSLog(@"%@",);

Comment: That is a NSData output. Convert that to a NSString or NSDictionary. Here are a few links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603047/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-nsdictionary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring

Comment: @Anil It is giving null when I am converting NSData to NSDictionary.

Comment: you want to share the images to fb or tweet

Comment: @deepti convert it into string as I mentioned above.or your response is something other than string data?

Comment: @Anil Thanks for your reply. Now I got the response . Actually AccessToken was missing on that.  Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can post your data in better way using AFNetworking framework. Samples are also provided on github.

http://afnetworking.com/

Answer (score 1):

[MGInstagram](https://github.com/mglagola/MGInstagram) and [DMActivityInstagram](https://github.com/coryalder/DMActivityInstagram) is a iOS Utility for posting Images to Instagram from your app.

```
// Uses our instagram instance to do a request
- (void) postMessage:(NSString *)message mediaId:(NSString *)mediaId {
    NSString* methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"media/%@/comments", mediaId];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = @{"text" : message};
    [m_instagram requestWithMethodName:methodName params:params httpMethod:@"POST" delegate:self];
}

// IGRequestDelegate method that is called once we get a response
- (void)request:(IGRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
  // post message was ok
}
- (void)request:(IGRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  // post message fails
}
```

Reference from  https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk/issues/27

if you are share the images to social network use below link it have sample app with tutorial

[share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios/](http://technopote.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

better to use  AFNetworking for post, bellow is a sample , please have a look

```
-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = 
        [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                        path:kAPIPath 
                                  parameters:params 
                   constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
                       //TODO: attach file if needed
    }];

    AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //success!
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //failure :(
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```