# Show error results from API Response JSON format on Alert View when 400 HTTP Response

Tags: ios, json

Want to achieve this like you see in the image

[image]

The following information below works properly but what i want to do is display to the user the response from the API because even when i validate the following fields, nick, pass_field, type_account , email. The API responds whether that username is in use or if the email is invalid. as you can see below. What i want to do is modify this code and make it response a alert to the user with the API response for each field the JSON only responds the following fields during 400 HTTP Response

{"nick": ["Username required"]}

{"nick": ["Username eddwinpaz is in use"]}

{"email": ["Email field is required"]}

{"email": ["Type a valid email"]}

{"pass_field": ["pass field is required"]}

Here is my response

```
2014-05-14 12:30:09.944 mobile-app[2337:60b] PostData: nick=&pass_field=&email=&type_account=0
2014-05-14 12:30:30.998 mobile-app[2337:60b] Response code: 400
2014-05-14 12:30:30.998 mobile-app[2337:60b] Response ==> {"nick": ["Username eddwinpaz is in use"]}
```

Here is my ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)registerClicked:(id)sender {
NSInteger success = 0;
@try {

        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"nick=%@&pass_field=%@&email=%@&type_account=%ld",[self.txtUsername text],
                         [self.txtPassword text],
                         [self.txtEmail text],
                         (long)[self.userType selectedSegmentIndex]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.samplewebsite.ca/user-register/?format=json"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        if ([response statusCode] == 201)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:&error];

            success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);


                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];

                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Your Account has been created, Now login" :0];
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];



        } else {

            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Registration Failed, Please check empty or invalid fields!" :0];
        }

}
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }

}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? The code you posted shows no attempt to do what you are asking. Try first and then update your question with a specific issue if you run into one.

Comment: I didn't understand a word of it

Comment: i want to show the JSON that comes as a result on alerts and not from iOS validation because the API validates if nick field exists alredy on database.

Comment: I put an answer that is along the lines of what you're looking for, but please reconsider not using an alert for this.

Comment: @LyricalPanda updated the question and added an image

Comment: @eddwinpaz I've updated my answer to reflect the changes. Thank you for being so open to switching from a `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot better than using an AlertView. To do this, add three labels with Right Justification above the fields (emailErrorLabel, nickErrorLabel, passErrorLabel).

Convert `responseData` into an `NSDictionary` so you can extract the keys. Then you'll have something like the following:

```
if ([response statusCode] == 201)
{ ... }
else if ([response statusCode] == 400)
{ 
   NSArray *keys = [responseData allKeys];
   for (NSString * key in keys)
   {
     if ([key isEqualToString:@"email"])
       emailErrorLabel.text = [responseData objectForKey:key];
     else if ([key isEqualToString:@"nick"])
       nickErrorLabel.text = [responseData objectForKey:key];
     else if ([key isEqualToString:@"pass_field"])
       passErrorLabel.text = [responseData objectForKey:key];
   }

}
```

Comment: this is REgisterViewController.h http://imageshack.com/a/img838/1282/rzeq.png and this is .m  http://imageshack.com/a/img845/2524/ehw8.png

Comment: Check this link out. ResponseData really shouldn't be a string when it's in that format. Change it to an `NSDictionary` based on the return you specified in your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603047/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-nsdictionary