# Parse this data from JSON to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm having some problems in parsing some data from a JSON to a NSDictionary, the data the JSON has inside follows the pattern:

```
    object =     (
            {
        "field1" = 2;
        "field2" = "something";
        array =             {
            "field3" = "anotherThing";
            booleanField = true;
           {
            };
            otherThing = "yay";
        };    
            },
         {
        "field1" = 2;
        "field2" = "something";
        array =             {
            "field3" = "anotherThing";
            booleanField = true;
           {
            };
            otherThing = "yay";
        };    
            } )
```

How can I create a `NSArray` with 2 `NSDictionaries`?

I expect I explained it simply

Thank you for your help

Comment: your JSON seems to be invalid...

Comment: You already have it converted into an array containing two dictionaries.  JSON would have `[` instead of `(`, `:` instead of `=`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *contentArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                         JSONObjectWithData:[aContentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                         options:0
                         error:&jsonParsingError];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate ([How to convert JSON serialized data to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603047/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-nsdictionary))

if your response is `object = (...);`

```
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *dictObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSArray *arr = dictObject[@"object"];
```

if your response is `(...)`;

```
NSError *err;
NSArray *arrObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked just like i needed!! it was this easy!! Regards!