# There and Back Again: Sending and receiving NSData through GameCenter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center

I'm working on a fun little turn-based iPhone game using GameCenter. This is my first time using the platform, and I could use a little help packing up the data to send, and then unpacking it.

These are the pieces of information I need to send and receive:

Prompt: A NSString with <256 characters.

Play: A Custom Object containing:
Prompt: The same prompt as above.
An NSMutableArray with 1-3 similar strings. (ORDER MATTERS)
A Player ID: Another NSString

Previous Plays: An NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays of Play objects.
(Max 10x8x5 = 400 NSStrings)

PlayedA: An NSArray of NSStrings, <1000
PlayedB: Same, <500

My question to you is, how can I pack these up so GameCenter will take them? If there was a way I could just create a container class for all this data, serialize it into an NSData Object, and then have the ability to unpack it on the other end that would be great.

Worst comes to worst, I could concatenate them into a giant string with my own delimiters and parse to and from it, but that would be really annoying. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would package it all into a dictionary, then convert it to NSData. Check out [How can I convert NSDictionary to NSData and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513075/how-can-i-convert-nsdictionary-to-nsdata-and-vice-versa) for more info on how to do the conversion