# Sending an image and text together to other peers through MultipeerConnectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I am using Apple **MultipeerConnectivity** framework and I am able to send the message to all the peers connected to it.

I am using:

```
- (BOOL)sendData:(NSData *)data toPeers:(NSArray *)peerIDs withMode:(MCSessionSendDataMode)mode error:(NSError **)error;
```

I am even able to send the image by converting it in `NSData`.

Problem is I am trying to send image and text together to other peers. I know there are three ways to send information to other peers:

**1.** `NSData`

**2.** `Resource`

**3.** `Stream`

So for sending an image and text together which method we should use and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use NSData for your task. Here is example:
Serialization to NSData:

```
NSString *string = @"Any String";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Any Image"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"string":string, @"imageData":imageData};
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
// Send |data| by MultipeerConnectivity
```

Deserialization to NSString and UIImage:

```
// Receive |data| by MultipeerConnectivity
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSString *string = dictionary[@"string"];
NSData *imageData = dictionary[@"imageData"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
```

Comment: Thanks i was also doing the same. Just found out here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513075/how-can-i-convert-nsdictionary-to-nsdata-and-vice-versa