# Replacement of dataWithContentsOfURL in AFNetworking

Tags: url, afnetworking

I found in [here](http://www.slideshare.net/waynehartman/working-with-afnetworking) that you should never use `dataWithContentsOfURL`.

I am new to AFNetworking. What is the correct (and simplest) way to replace `dataWithContentsOfURL` using AFNetworking? For example, how to replace:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a little late, but I think this is what youre looking for (courtesy of the [AFNetworking ReadMe on Github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)) :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Then, if you need to, you can then convert responseData into NSData using ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513075/how-can-i-convert-nsdictionary-to-nsdata-and-vice-versa)):

```
NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:responseObject];
```